# Get one value of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code like this

```
    <article>
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet con
    <span class="post-labels">Label: 
        <a href="#">Picture</a>, 
        <a href="#">Panorama</a>, 
    </span>
</article>

<article>
    <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 
    <span class="post-labels">Label: 
        <a href="#">Foto</a>,
    </span>
</article>
```

I need get value (picture, foto) in jquery. and add value to class of article

```
$('article').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.post-labels').length) {        
        var cl = $('a').text();
        $(this).addClass(cl);
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first anchor you need to use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('article').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.post-labels').length) {        
        var cl = $(this).find('.post-labels > a').eq(0).text();
        $(this).addClass(cl);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Target to `post-labels a` not just `a`:

```
$('article').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.post-labels').length) {        
        var cl = $(this).find('.post-labels a').text();
        $(this).addClass(cl);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery :

```
var a1_text = $('#a1').text();
```

JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML
```